# how to fill system.data.dataset from oracle.dataacess.client.oracledataadapter?

Tags: vb.net

I have installed Oracle 10g Express Edition database on a server and install the client on my PC.

Now, I`m developing a vb.net application using visual studio 2005 and I need to use the oracle 10g express edition database. So I initialize the connection using the following connection string:

```
_connectionString = "User Id=Graphya;Password=Graphya;Data Source=gis64:1522/XE;"
```

Then I define new OracleDataAdapter, and I use the following code to fill a dataset:

```
Dim insertCommand As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()
Dim commandTextTemplate As String = "INSERT INTO {0}(" & g_pfldUsername & ", " & g_pfldSubject & ") VALUES (?, ?)"
insertCommand.CommandText = String.Format(commandTextTemplate,TABLE_NAME)
insertCommand.Connection = Me.Connection
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter(g_pfldUsername, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, g_pfldUsername))
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter(g_pfldSubject, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, g_pfldSubject))
 
_OracleDataAdapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand
 
_OracleDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet, TABLE_NAME)
```

So after debugging this code I got the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' to type 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand'.

Comment: check `Dim commandTextTemplate`  i think you are not creating correct query. refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter.insertcommand.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Davideg: my code is c# to fill data set

```
OleDbConnection cnOra = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=myOracleServer;" 
              + "user id=myUID;password=myPWD;"
              + "persist security info=false;");
        OleDbCommand cmdPerson = new OleDbCommand
        + ("{call PackPerson.allPerson({resultset 3, ssn, fname, lname})}", cnOra);

    OleDbDataAdapter daPerson = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdPerson);
    cnOra.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    daPerson.Fill(ds,"Person");
    this.dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Person"];
    cnOra.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks R.D. ... you provide me with the best solution...
I just wondering if I can get your advise in one more little thing: What is the Oledb datatypes corresponding to oracle datatypes(Number, Varchar2, TimeStamp).....Can you help me plz...

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetEmailsByPageName(ByVal pageName As String) As DataSet
    Dim cn As New OracleConnection
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand

    cn = New OracleConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    cmd = New OracleCommand("ORACLEDBA.PACKAGE_EMAIL.SP_EMAIL_LISTING_BY_NAME")
    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.BindByName = True

    Dim paramCursor As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter("email_list_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor)
    With cmd.Parameters
        .Add(New OracleParameter("a_page_name", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = pageName
        .Add("a_err_code", OracleDbType.Int32, Data.ParameterDirection.Output)
        .Add("a_err_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 300).Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.Output
        .Add(paramCursor).Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.Output
    End With

    Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dsEmail As DataSet = New DataSet
    Try
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dsEmail)
        Return dsEmail
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        da.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cn.Dispose()
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```